# Is this possible to have triangular PictureBox instead of the rectangular one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, picturebox

Is this possible to have triangular `PictureBox` control in windows forms instead of the rectangular one?

Answer (score 5):

You have some options, for example:

- You can set the region of control to a triangle.
- You can only paint in a triangular area of the control.

**Example 1**

In this example, the region of control limited to a triangular shape.

```
public class TriangularPictureBox:PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        using (var p = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            p.AddPolygon(new Point[] {
                new Point(this.Width / 2, 0), 
                new Point(0, Height), 
                new Point(Width, Height) });

            this.Region = new Region(p);
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Example 2**

In this example, the painting will be done only on a triangular area of the control.

```
public class TriangularPictureBox:PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        using (var p = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            p.AddPolygon(new Point[] {
                new Point(this.Width / 2, 0), 
                new Point(0, Height), 
                new Point(Width, Height) });

            pe.Graphics.SetClip(p);
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]