# Set CircularPictureBox Border Color

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I'm creating a custom PictureBox.

As you can see, it's a PictureBox designed for profile photos

[image]

Well, this is the class of the CircularPictureBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hector.Framework.Controls
{
    public class CircularPictureBox : PictureBox
    {
        private Color _idlecolor = Color.White;

        public CircularPictureBox()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            this.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);

            using (var gpath = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                var brush = new SolidBrush(this.IdleBorderColor);
                var pen = new Pen(brush, 5);
                var outrect = new Rectangle(-1, -1, this.Width + 5, this.Height + 5);
                gpath.AddEllipse(outrect);
                pe.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                pe.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, gpath);

                brush.Dispose();
                pen.Dispose();
                gpath.Dispose();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);

            using (var gpath = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                var rect = new Rectangle(1, 1, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
                gpath.AddEllipse(rect);
                this.Region = new Region(gpath);
                gpath.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public Color IdleBorderColor
        {
            get => this._idlecolor;
            set => this._idlecolor = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that since it is a control that can be used from the designer, I want it to have properties such as edge width or border color.

I started testing with the color, but it is that whenever I change the color,
Visual Studio shows me an error message saying that **The value of the property is not valid**

Comment: Umm, what values are you putting in that are invalid?

Comment: @ForeverZer0 In the Visual Studio designer, the property created by my IdleColor, shows me this message by changing the color

Comment: Have you checked the designer .cs file of the form to see what the value is?  Or remove the call to method_0 in the property setter. This might help you track down the source of the problem.

Comment: I can see one nasty bug, do not assign the Region property in the paint event.  Too many side-effects, it causes paint to get fired again and you'll see VS burning 100% core.  It belongs in OnResize().  And this also bombs your code since you forgot to call Dispose() on the pen and the brush, the show is over after 5000 paints, in turn causing VS to get pretty upset.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 method_0, create this method because in the ordinary way it does not work, so create a method that you could also call from the set accessor

Comment: @HansPassant Do not forget to call Dispose, I did it this way to test the color change in the designer and then accommodate everything

Comment: I understand its purpose, and can follow the code, but to track the origin of the error you are getting, could remove and see if that method being called while in design mode is the problem.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 If I remove the method, the control works without errors, but the color does not change

Comment: Check for design mode before calling method_0.  (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)

Comment: Not setting `Region` is preferred. If you set the region to a circular region, you will see a jagged border around the picture box, while you can use `SetClip` to a circular path to force the control to draw itself in a circle shape. Then for the transparency effect, just set back color to `Color.Transparent`. To see an example of both cases take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467736/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few modifications to your code, to highlight some features that can be useful in the design of Custom Control.

The modifications I've made I think are self-explanatory.
However, take a look at the `OnPaint` event. The `e.Graphics.Clip` Region lets you hide all graphics parts that are not in the selected region. This implies that when you drag the control in Design Mode, the Image will be clipped and won't be seen outside the region area.

The [PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode) and [SmoothingMode.AntiAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode) contributes to the overall quality of the rendering (there are commented out options that can useful in other situations).

The calculation of the Border offset must reference the BorderSize width, and scaled accordingly. The Pen object draws starting from the middle of its size. If a Pen has a size of 3 pixels, 1 Pixel is drawn on the border, one outside the area and one inside (weird? Maybe).

The transparency settings is just a "fake" here.
It might be used effectively in other situations (it should read "Platforms").

```
public class CircularPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Color borderColor;
    private int penSize;
    private Color alphaColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255,255,255);
    private bool enhancedBuffering;

    public CircularPictureBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                      ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                      ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | 
                      ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
                      ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.enhancedBuffering = true;
        this.bitmap = null;
        this.borderColor = Color.Silver;
        this.penSize = 7;
        this.BackColor = alphaColor;
        this.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        //e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        //e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        if (this.Region != null) e.Graphics.Clip = this.Region;
        var rect = this.ClientRectangle;
        if (bitmap != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, rect);
        }

        rect.Inflate(-penSize / 2 + 1, -penSize / 2 + 1);
        using (var pen = new Pen(borderColor, penSize)) {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath()) {
            path.AddEllipse(this.ClientRectangle);
            path.CloseFigure();
            using (Region region = new Region(path)) {
                this.Region = region.Clone();
            }
        }
    }

    [Description("Gets or Sets the Image displayed by the control"), Category("Appearance")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true)]
    public Bitmap Bitmap
    {
        get { return bitmap; }
        set { bitmap = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    [Description("Gets or Sets the size of the Border"), Category("Behavior")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true)]
    public int BorderSize
    {
        get { return penSize; }
        set { penSize = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    [Description("Gets or Sets the Color of Border drawn around the Image.")]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true)]
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { borderColor = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    [Description("Enables or disables the control OptimizedDoubleBuffering feature")]
    [Category("Useful Features")] //<= "Useful feature" is a custom category
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true)]
    public bool EnhancedBuffering
    {
        get { return enhancedBuffering; }
        set { enhancedBuffering = value; 
              SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, value);  
              UpdateStyles();
        }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
    public new Image ErrorImage
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { base.ErrorImage = null; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
    public new Image InitialImage
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { base.InitialImage = null; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
    public new Image BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { base.BackgroundImage = null; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public new Image Image {
        get { return null; }
        set { base.Image = null; } 
    }
}
```

Some `System.ComponentModel` Attributes that can help shaping the Control.

For example, [Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute) and [Category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute) attributes:
(These have been inserted in the custom Property `BorderColor` of your control).

```
    [Description("Gets or Sets the Color of the Border drawn around the Image.")
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(true)]
```

Description of course explains the user what the Property is for.
Category is used to give the Properties an organic disposition inside the [PropertyGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid). You can use standard names (`Appearance`, `Behavior` etc.) or specify anything else.
Give the `Category` a custom name and it will be listed among the others, when the `Categorized` view is in use.

The `Image` property of the Custom Control has been hidden and substituted with a `Bitmap` Property:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), BrowsableAttribute(false)]
```

The [EditorBrowsable Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute) is a hint to Intellisense that lets you determine whether to show a property or method in the Popup menu. It can be `Never`, `Always` or `Advanced` (for those who know how to reach VS `Options`). Properties and Methods will be Hidden when the Custom Control is deployed (as a dll), not while you are designing it.

The [BrowsableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute) Attribute (or just `[Browsable]`) allows to specify whether that Property should be shown in the PropertyGrid.

The [DesignerSerializationVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility)

> With the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` Attribute, you can indicate
> whether the value for a property is **`Visible`**, and should be persisted
> in initialization code, **`Hidden`**, and should not be persisted in
> initialization code, or consists of **`Content`**, which should have
> initialization code generated for each public, not hidden property of
> the object assigned to the property.

Also interesting:
[TypeConverter(typeof(System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter)

With this Attribute, you can instruct to list the Public Properties of a Class Object in the PropertyGrid.
This Class Object can be an internal Class that serializes a complex Property of a Control.
The [TypeConverter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) is very interesting itself.

Comment: Well, I copied your code, but when assigning an image, it simply is not shown

Comment: How do you assign the Image? Have you noticed that the `Image` Property is disabled? You have to use the new `Bitmap` Property to assign an image to the control. Drop it on a Form and look at the PropertyGrid.

Comment: Oh, perfect, it's that I was using the Image property through the code, but yes, it's Bitmap, thanks

Comment: I modified that just to show how a default property can be suppressed and substituted with a custom one. I though you could use this class as *play ground*. You can of course revert it back to standard behavior. Won't affect the results.

Comment: Well, if it is true that I already knew that by using the keyword new you could hide a member to create a custom one, but I did not think it was necessary for what I wanted to do

Comment: Ufff, you saved me, because I thought that SO I was not going to answer my question and that it was going to be like one of those unanswered questions