# Custom shape your user control or panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, gdi+

I can make a usercontrol/panel transparent but is there anyway to customize the shape of the usercontrol in Winforms yourself, like for this example [Shape Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKkQC.png)?

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **custom** - not "costum" ....

Comment: Take a look at some posts like [Rectangular user control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35467199/3110834), [Round corner user control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32987649/3110834), ... Implement the feature. Ask a specific question if you faced with any problem. Please take a look at [ASK] and also read hot to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Also in the image which you shared is really hard to see the shape of the control.

Comment: I think you can change the "OnPaintBackground" and "onPaint" event of user control, with overrides.

Comment: I see only rectangles.