# How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, rounded-corners, visual-artifacts

I have a `Form` which contains:

1. a `TrackBar` (minimum = 1, maximum = 200, represents zoom percent);
2. a `UserControl` with `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None`.

## Relevant code

### Form1

#### From designer code

```
trackBar1.Value = 100;
BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

#### From code-behind

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControl11.SetZoomFactor(trackBar1.Value / 100F);
}
```

### UserControl1

```
internal float MyBaseWidth;

public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyBaseWidth = Width;

    SetZoomFactor(1);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
    e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, GraphicsPathWithBorder);
}

internal GraphicsPath GraphicsPathWithBorder;

internal void SetZoomFactor(float z)
{
    Width = (int)(MyBaseWidth * z);

    GraphicsPathWithBorder = RoundedCornerRectangle(ClientRectangle);
    Region = new Region(GraphicsPathWithBorder);
}

internal static GraphicsPath RoundedCornerRectangle(Rectangle r)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    float size = 10 * 2F;

    path.StartFigure();

    path.AddArc(r.X, r.Y,
        size, size, 180, 90);
    path.AddArc((r.X + (r.Width - size)), r.Y,
        size, size, 270, 90);
    path.AddArc((r.X + (r.Width - size)), (r.Y + (r.Height - size)),
        size, size, 0, 90);
    path.AddArc(r.X, (r.Y + (r.Height - size)),
        size, size, 90, 90);

    path.CloseFigure();

    return path;
}
```

## Initial screenshot

[image: initially]

## Screenshot after using the trackbar

[image: after zoom]

The right side of the yellow border becomes invisible after zooming out, and when zooming in there are multiple yellow borders on the right side.

**Update:**

The answer Works, but there is a part of the control that goes beyond the border. Screenshot for top-right corner, for `curveSize = 20`:

[image: curve 1]

and for `curveSize = 24`:

[image: curve 2]

Comment: You need to invalidate the control after changing the size, manually by overriding `OnSizeChanged` and calling `Invalidate` or automatically by setting `ResizeRedraw=true`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991419/3110834)?

Comment: @RezaAghaei `ResizeRedraw=true` Works but the border is not antialiased.

Comment: It's a different story. In fact for smooth edges you should forget about changing the region. Instead you need to create a control which supports transparent `BackColor`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different method to draw the Border and the content of the User Control that should also *cure* the artifacts generated when the control is redrawn.

When you create a Region for a Control and then you paint the Region as it is, the outer borders of the painting are not anti-aliased: the aliased pixels fall outside the Region. The same effect of course is applied when a border is painted around the bounds of the Region.

Here, I apply a [Scale Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.scale) and a [Translate Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.translate) that *scale and move* the bounds of the Region on the inside of the outer Region that defines the control's bounds.
The size of the scale and the translate transformations are determined by the Pen size.
More information on the Matrix usage here: [Flip the GraphicsPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182901/7444103)

In this case, when the borders are painted, the outer, anti-aliased, section of the border is inside the Region bounds and the anti-aliasing is preserved.
The background color of the Control is set to `Color.Transparent` (a User Control supports color transparency on its own).

I've also added a couple of (non decorated) properties that allow to define the inner Color (the Control's `BackColor`) and Size and Color of the Border. The rest is more or less what it was before.

Sample results:

[image: Rounded Zoomable UserControl]

---

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

public partial class RoundControl : UserControl
{
    private GraphicsPath GraphicsPathWithBorder;
    private float MyBaseWidth;
    private float m_PenSize = 2f;
    private Color m_BorderColor = Color.Yellow;
    private Color m_FillColor = Color.Green;

    public RoundControl()
    {
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        MyBaseWidth = Width;
    }

    public float BorderSize
    {
        get => m_PenSize;
        set {
            m_PenSize = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get => m_BorderColor;
        set {
            m_BorderColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Color FillColor
    {
        get => m_FillColor;
        set {
            m_FillColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e) {
        UpdateRegion();
        base.OnLayout(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        RectangleF rect = GraphicsPathWithBorder.GetBounds();
        float scaleX = 1 - ((m_PenSize + 1) / rect.Width);
        float scaleY = 1 - ((m_PenSize + 1) / rect.Height);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(m_BorderColor, m_PenSize))
        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(m_FillColor))
        using (Matrix mx = new Matrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, pen.Width / 2, pen.Width / 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.Transform = mx;
            e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, GraphicsPathWithBorder);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, GraphicsPathWithBorder);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    internal void SetZoomFactor(float z) {
        int newWidth = (int)(MyBaseWidth * z);
        if (newWidth <= (30 + m_PenSize * 2)) return;
        Width = newWidth;
        UpdateRegion();
    }


    private void UpdateRegion() {
        GraphicsPathWithBorder = RoundedCornerRectangle(ClientRectangle);
        Region = new Region(GraphicsPathWithBorder);
        Invalidate();
    }

    private GraphicsPath RoundedCornerRectangle(Rectangle r)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        // Fixed curve size since we only scale on X-dimension
        // Otherwise, adjust also considering the height
        float curveSize = 10 * 2.4F;

        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(r.Right - curveSize, r.Y, curveSize, curveSize, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(r.Right - curveSize, r.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(r.X, r.Bottom - curveSize, curveSize, curveSize, 90, 90);
        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `BackColor = Color.Transparent` as in the description? When coding for *production*, you should override/eliminate all those properties that a User must not tamper with. If it's for yourself, you can keep the property visible and set it in the designer. Or use the `OnPaint` method and Paint the Background yourself. Or override `OnPaintBackground`. Or use `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);`, You'll have no background so, again, you can paint it yourself to whatever you like.