# TextBox Border-Radius in .NET Core WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, windows-forms-designer, windows-forms-core

I'm trying to border radius, but there is no such parameter in the windows form. Is there a document or code sequence you can recommend?

Comment: There's no such thing. If you want to design a Control with rounded border (if that's what *trying to border radius* means), you have to draw it yourself.

Comment: See: (UserControl) [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103) -- (Custom translucent Control): [Translucent circular Control with text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103), (Custom Rounded Button): [How to make a custom Button responsiveness smoother?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62778689/7444103) -- All with smooth borders.

Comment: Also, see how to draw smooth border o a Custom Control using Regions (which don't usually support anti-aliasing): [How to draw a shape using GraphicsPath to create the Region of a Custom Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075782/7444103). The same *logic* applies to any other type of shape.

Comment: @RoseTyler Are you looking for BorderWidth property? Something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuTV7.png) which has a wider border comparing to the original text box border?