# Is there anyway to create a rounded corner button like this in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I was able to create a button like this with a custom image and rounded corner button but when both of them loaded they loaded desperately which ruins the UI, I wonder if there is any way to create a button like this without custom images.

[image: Figure 1 - Button]

And here is the custom image I used.

[image]

Comment: You definitely can, if you are using a third party framework.

Comment: which frameworks?

Comment: You can use `Bunifu`, `GunaUI`. Every properties of their button has a `Border Radius` that can make their corner round as what you like

Comment: You can build a UserControl with transparent background, create a Region using a GraphicsPath that defines the inner borders of that Control, then paint your shape inside the Region with an offset equal to half the Pen used to draw the border - 1 pixel. This creates an anti-aliased *contour* that would not be rendered simply defining a Region (which doesn't support anti-aliasing). The procedure is described here: [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103)