# Is it possible to give a border radius for evertything

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, radius

Hello guys do u know how to make border radius on windows forms c#?

I tried dlls but they only work for the form.
Do you know a way to round the corners of picute boxes,textboxes,button etc.

Comment: It's simple enough with a UserControl, e.g., [How to avoid visual artifacts of colored border of zoomable UserControl with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103). But you may probably want to test WPF *Controls*.

Comment: Just don't do that... If you use WinForms, use it as it is. WinForms has its own style and it's good as Microsoft defined it. If you want fancy stylish ugly stuff, use HTML or something.