# Rounded textbox border double borders

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am trying to create a custom textbox control with rounded corners. But somehow, I cannot override the default border and getting a result like below:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Desktop.CustomControls
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;
        private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;

        private Color borderColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(115)))), ((int)(((byte)(115)))), ((int)(((byte)(115)))));
        private int borderSize = 1;
        private int borderRadius = 8;

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set
            {
                borderColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        public CustomTextBox()
        {
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None; // Remove the default border style
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT) // WM_PAINT message
            {
                using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    using (Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
                    {
                        g.DrawRoundedRectangle(borderPen
                            , 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1
                            , borderRadius);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class GraphicsExtensions
    {
        public static void DrawRoundedRectangle(this Graphics g, Pen pen, float x, float y, float width, float height, float radius)
        {
            float diameter = radius * 2;
            SizeF sizeF = new SizeF(diameter, diameter);
            RectangleF arc = new RectangleF(x, y, sizeF.Width, sizeF.Height);

            // Top-left arc
            g.DrawArc(pen, arc, 180, 90);
            // Top-right arc
            arc.X = x + width - diameter;
            g.DrawArc(pen, arc, 270, 90);
            // Bottom-right arc
            arc.Y = y + height - diameter;
            g.DrawArc(pen, arc, 0, 90);
            // Bottom-left arc
            arc.X = x;
            g.DrawArc(pen, arc, 90, 90);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're overriding `WndProc` (which I think it's a mistake) and the first thing you do is call it's base - `base.WndProc(ref m);` That's probably what's drawing the border. I've done this kind of thing before, don't have the code with me right now but I'll have it tomorrow. Hopefully, I'll remember to post an answer.

Comment: You're drawing inside the Client Area. The non-client area has already been drawn. You could (theoretically) handle `WM_NCCALSIZE` and `WM_NCPAINT` (also carefully handling the `GetDcEx()` calls and a couple of its undocumented flags) to setup a rounded clip Region. You could also add the TextBox to an UserControl drawn [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794097/7444103) and expose the properties you care about. Also painful, but a bit less so (at least, you can easily anti-alias the borders)