# GraphicsPath.AddArc gives the wrong angle

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm running into the problem that my rounded corners method returns non-uniform corners. 
Method:

```
GraphicsPath GetRoundedPath(Rectangle r, int radius, bool topRight = true, bool topLeft = true, bool bottomLeft = true, bool bottomRight = true)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

    if (topLeft)
        path.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.X, r.Y, r.Right, r.Y);

    if (topRight)
        path.AddArc(r.Right - radius, r.Y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.Right, r.Y, r.Right, r.Height);

    if (bottomRight)
        path.AddArc(r.Right - radius, r.Bottom - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.Right, r.Bottom, r.Right, r.Height);

    if (bottomLeft)
        path.AddArc(r.X, r.Bottom - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.X, r.Bottom, r.X, r.Y);

    return path;
}
```

When invoke:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.BackColor = Color.Red;
p.Size = new Size(200, 200);
Controls.Add(p);
p.Region = new Region(GetRoundedPath(new Rectangle(p.ClientRectangle, 30, true, true, true, true));
p.Location = new Point(200, 200);
```

Return: 
[image] 
It is noticeable that the upper left corner is drawn normally, the upper right and lower left are crooked, and the lower left is even crooked. 

After, I noticed that exactly one pixel was not visible on the right and bottom, then I opened the Paint(program) and painted it myself and got even corners: 
[image]

What I tried:
**Passed less Rectangle to GetRoundedPath** 
`GetRoundedPath(new Rectangle(p.ClientRectangle.X, p.ClientRectangle.Y, p.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, p.ClientRectangle.Height - 1), 30, true, true, true, true)`
The control just became a pixel smaller in width and height.
**Don't to change Control.Region, to use Graphics.FillPath instead**

```
p.Paint += (s, e) =>
{
    e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, GetRoundedPath(p.ClientRectangle, 30, true, true, true, true));
};
```

Nothing has changed, I also tried to use it in conjunction with the first
**Increase radius for individual corners**

```
int oppositeRadius = (int)Math.Round(radius * 1.5)
...
```

The corners became stretched and looked more like slanted lines

**UPD:** I found similar post - [Strange GraphicsPath.AddArc() behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616383/strange-graphicspath-addarc-behaviour) but it work only with Region and all corners, when I have problem with GraphicsPath

Answer (score 0):

It looks like off by 1 pixel for center of arc error. Maybe try something like:

```
GraphicsPath GetRoundedPath(Rectangle r, int radius, bool topRight = true, bool topLeft = true, bool bottomLeft = true, bool bottomRight = true)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

    if (topLeft)
        path.AddArc(r.X, r.Y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.X, r.Y, r.Right, r.Y);

    if (topRight)
        path.AddArc(r.Right - radius - 1, r.Y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.Right, r.Y, r.Right, r.Height);

    if (bottomRight)
        path.AddArc(r.Right - radius - 1, r.Bottom - radius - 1, radius, radius, 0, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.Right, r.Bottom, r.Right, r.Height);

    if (bottomLeft)
        path.AddArc(r.X, r.Bottom - radius - 1, radius, radius, 90, 90);
    else path.AddLine(r.X, r.Bottom, r.X, r.Y);

    return path;
}
```

Comment: The corners are still crooked, the figure has only decreased by 1 pixel.
Comparison - https://imgur.com/a/iBIAEsk

Comment: I was reading docs for addArc method you use (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdipluspath/nf-gdipluspath-graphicspath-addarc(int_int_int_int_real_real) and noticed, that in this signature your radius param is not a radius, but full width or height of arc. So maybe radius/2